# python cannot load en_core_web_lg module in azure app service with docker image

Tags: python, docker, nlp, azure-web-app-service, spacy

I have a flask python app that uses a spacy model (md or lg).  I am running in a docker container in VSCode and all work correctly on my laptop.

When I push the image to my azure container registry the app restarts but it doesn't seem to get past this line in the log:

> Initiating warmup request to the container.

If I comment out the line `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')`, the website loads fine (of course it doesn't work as expected).

I am installing the model in the docker file after installing the requirements.txt:
`RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg`.

Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6
EXPOSE 5000

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# steps needed for scipy
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev libc-dev build-essential
RUN pip install -U pip

# Install pip requirements
ADD requirements.txt.
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "Application.webapp:app"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `en_core_web_sm` instead `en_core_web_lg`.
You can install the module by `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Comment: interesting...that did work.  Only issue is I want to use the vector feature of space which is only in md and lg and neither of those work.   thanks

Comment: Not a solution, since the sm model clearly does not perform as well as the lg (a few MB size for sm vs ~700MB for lg).

Comment: Definitely not a solution as lg is a much larger model and that's where Azure is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed you asked your question over on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00c9ca7f-9e80-48af-8571-f88ede1a63d4/nlp-spacy-model-issues-in-docker-image-on-azure?forum=azureappconfiguration). If en_core_web_sm worked but _md and _lg doesn't, increase your timeout by setting WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT to a value up to 1800 sec). The size might be taking a while to load the image and simply times out.

If you already done that, email us at AzCommunity[at]microsoft[dot]com ATTN Ryan so we can take a closer look. Include your subscription id and app service name.

Comment: WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT hasn't solved the problem. Is there any other way?

Comment: Which en_core_web are you using, _md or _lg?

Comment: I'm trying to use _lg, works fine with _sm, but not _lg.